# finding $g(x)$ when $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are given.

Tags: polynomials

I'm currently stuck solving this question.
$f(x) = x^3 - 5x^2 + x - 7 $
$f(g(x)) = 27x^3 + 90x^2 + 78x - 2  $
I know that I can find $g(x)$ by finding the inverse function of $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(f(g(x))$ but in this case it looks like it is impossible to find inverse function of $f(x)$. So is there an easier method of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And *how* would you find $f^{-1}$? It doesn't exist, since $f$ is *not* bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no there isn't a better way (although finding the inverse of this $f$ might prove to be a problem since it doesn't exist).  However, in this problem, it might be best to stare at the problem to see if an idea appears.

- We see that both $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are polynomials, so it makes sense to guess that $g(x)$ might also be a polynomial.
- The leading term of $f(x)$ is $x^3$, while the leading term of $f(g(x))$ is $27x^3=(3x)^3$.  Therefore, we might guess that the leading term of $g(x)$ is $3x$, which is then getting cubed to get $27x^3$.
- At this point, we're guessing that $g(x)=3x+a$ for some $a$.  We could just substitute our guess for $g(x)$ into $f(x)$ to get an expression of
  \begin{align*}
  f(g(x))&=(3x+a)^3-5(3x+a)^2+(3x+a)-7\\
  &=(27x^3+3(3x)^2a+3(3x)a^2+a^3)-5(9x^2+2(3x)a+a^2)+(3x+a)-7\\
  &=27x^3+(27a-45)x^2+(9a^2-30a+3)x+(a^3-5a^2+a-7).
  \end{align*}
- Now, we look at the $x^2$ term of $f(g(x))$, which is $90x^2$.  On the other hand, the $x^2$ term of our guess is $(27a-45)x^2$, and these should be equal.  In other words, $90=27a-45$.  Solving for $a$, we get $a=5$.
- Now that we have a guess of $a=5$, we can take our $g(x)=3a+5$ and hope that $f(g(x))$ is correct by plugging in.  Plugging into our formula above gives exactly the form given, so we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an easier method. Just write $g(x)=ax+b$ and compute $f(g(x))$. Comparison of the coefficients of $x^3$ gives $a=3$, and comparison of the coefficients of $x^2$ gives $b=5$. Hence
$$
g(x)=3x+5.
$$
Note that the degree of $g$ cannot be bigger than $1$, because otherwise the degree of $f(g(x))$ would be bigger than $3$.

Comment: It is not given that $g$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Like it is not given that $f\in K[X]$ for some field $K$ of characteristic zero. Probably the OP means this, but has not specified.

Comment: @KaboMurphy That doesn't really matter. When looking for a solution, one is allowed to hope that the solution is nice, assume the solution is nice, and if one finds a solution with such an assumption, then great! If not, then you're almost back at square 1, true. But nothing has been lost other than a minute of calculation. If one is asked to find _all_ such $g$, then that's a different matter.